# Show that the transformations are linear

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm a little confused with this  question:
Let $W=V \bigoplus U$. where U and V are subspaces of W. Let $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ The transformations of W in W such that $w=u+v$ of W (u $\in$ U and v $\in$ V) associate, respectively, u and v, that is, $P_{1}(w)=u$ and $P_{2}(w)=v$. Show that $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are linear.

Well i don't even know exactly how to start, but here is my trial:
I defined
$$P_{1}: W \rightarrow U, P_{1}(w)=u.\\
P_{2}: W \rightarrow V, P_{2}(w)=v.$$

So what I'd have to do was just prove that $P_{1}(w_{1}+w_{2})= P_{1}(w_{1})+P_{1}(w_{1})$ and $P_{1}({\lambda}w)={\lambda}P_{1}(w)$. The same for $P_{2}$. But since i have no information about the elements of the given spaces, i don't know how to proceed or even if my trial is right.
If you guys could give any tip of how to solve this it would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w_1,w_2\in W$. Then there exist unique $u_1,u_2\in U$ and $v_1,v_2\in V$ such that $w_1=u_1+v_1$ and $w_2=u_2+v_2$.

Also, for $w_1+w_2\in W$, there exist **unique** $u\in U, v\in V$ such that $w_1+w_2=u+v$, which means $P_1(w_1+w_2)=u$ and $P_2(w_1+w_2)=v$ by definition of the maps.

But we also know that $w_1+w_2=u_1+v_1+u_2+v_2=(u_1+u_2)+(v_1+v_2)$, with $(u_1+u_2)\in U$ and $(v_1+v_2)\in V$. Due to the uniqueness of the decomposition of $w_1+w_2$ as a sum of vectors in $U$ and $V$, we realize that $u=u_1+u_2$ and $v=v_1+v_2$.

Thus we get $P_1(w_1+w_2)=u=u_1+u_2=P_1(w_1)+P_2(w_2)$. Similarly for $P_2(w_1+w_2)$.

I'll leave it to you to prove that $P_1(\lambda w)=\lambda P_1(w)$ and $P_2(\lambda w)=\lambda P_2(w)$.

Comment: I can do the last part. Thank you so much!